# pairing dates under same column in my sql

Tags: mysql

How do I pair dates under same column in my sql?

Table looks like this:

```
id | user       | type        | date
---+------------+-------------+-------------
 1 |          1 |    login    |  2014-03-19 15:41:52
 2 |          1 |    login    |  2014-03-19 19:41:52
 3 |          1 |    logout   |  2014-03-19 21:41:52
 4 |          2 |    login    |  2014-03-20 19:41:52
 5 |          2 |    logout   |  2014-03-20 20:41:52
 6 |          3 |    login    |  2014-03-21 19:41:52
 7 |          4 |    login    |  2014-03-21 19:42:52
 8 |          4 |    logout   |  2014-03-21 21:41:52
10 |          5 |    login    |  2014-03-19 21:45:52
11 |          5 |    login    |  2014-03-19 21:46:52
12 |          3 |    logout   |  2014-03-19 21:51:52
13 |          5 |    logout   |  2014-03-19 22:41:52
```

The aim is to pair one login to one logout.
In this example user 1 has 2 logins and 1 logout.

The first login should be disregarded, and the most recent login should be paired with the minimum logout: That is pairing login id=2 and logout id=3

Comment: What you mean by pairing? Can you show the example of desired result?

Comment: result should be like this -> user 1  2014-03-19 19:41:52     2014-03-19  21:41:52

Comment: what about logins without logout?

Comment: Do you ever have a situation where a user could login with two different sessions before logging out of either? (via multiple browsers or devices, for example)

Comment: i try counting the difference of time,  there is actually another column in this table that i use to group the result.  The result I got count the time difference between the logout id=3 and login id=1

Comment: 10,11 rows: user 5 loginned twice without logout between

Comment: i think there is because that is what i have right now, it is really not login /logout  it is more of viewin / viewout

Comment: don't need to do this in sql... do this in your db client language

Comment: vp_arth, i got your point but that is the case i have right now.  i cän't tell you now if the design of the database has some lapses or what.

Comment: all you need from sql - sort by users and then by time... the rest you can analyze in you regular PL

Comment: vp_arth your suggestion might be good.  but as of the moment i am constraint to do it in mysql

Comment: Could your final result have multiple entries for each user (assuming they logged in & logged out numerous times) OR do you just want 1 entry per user?

Comment: AgRizzo,  yes there are multiple entries, that is, there could be multiple pair of login/logout from same user

Comment: vp_arth, it is actually faster than what i have done.  i'll check on this more, especially on how it behaves once i have incorporated the rest of the requirements. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Easy ...

```
select 
  user,
  type,
  max(date)
from  
  user_table
group by
  user,
  type
```

The first query gets the max login and logout dates, but it sounds like you want them matched. I would need more information to write up a more clear script. From what you have given it sounds like you want the query below.

```
select
  t1.user,
  t1.max_login_date,
  t1.max_logout_date
from
  (select
    user,
    max(date) max_login_date
  from
    user_table
  where
    type = 'login'
  group by
    user) t1

  left join
      (select
      user,
      max(date) max_logout_date
    from
      user_table
    where
      type = 'logout'
    group by
      user) t2 on
      t2.user = t1.user
```

This query gets the max login date per user and you want to match the max logout date with that login date.

Comment: This returns only the last logon, not combination of all of them..?

Comment: Sorry the logout should be changed for minimum instead of max. Not sure why you would want a combination of them all since the question doesn't ask for a combination. If you want a combination just remove the max.

Comment: Even with min, it will pair user's first logout with user's last login, e.g. for this one it will be user 3's last login on 21/3 and paired with last logout on 19/3, which doesn't really make sense, as it is obviously not the correct pair...

Comment: i have to consider combination because users might have multiple entries of login/logout.  i have to count the difference of each login and logout and count how many times he/she has login and sumup the total time for that user

Comment: if you want the difference then you should just do a count of logins vs logouts and group by user then compare the two.

Comment: Tomas Pastircak,  it was just posting error it is not 19/3 it is 21/3

Answer (score 0):

something like this may work and should return all combinations from the table, but the performance may be getting worse as the table fills. For better performance, consider adding unique generated SessionId to the table, which will be same for both Login and Logout.

```
SELECT t1.user, t1.date loginDate, t2.date LogoutDate 
FROM table t1 
LEFT JOIN table t2 
    ON t1.user = t2.user AND t1.type = 'login' and t2.type = 'logout' AND t1.Date < t2.Date 
LEFT JOIN table t3 
    ON t3.user = t1.user AND t3.type = 'login' and t3.date < t2.date 
WHERE t3.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to pick up related login **:)**

There are login and logout fields in result set...
It catch almost all true pairs...
It works if correct sequence login/logout only...
**Very heavy** query, I suggest to move this logic to php(or other your lang) side...

```
set @ll=null;
SELECT t1.pk,t1.u, t1.t logout, related login FROM
(SELECT 
  @rl:=IF((a.a='<'), (@ll), null) related,
  IF((a.a='>'), @ll:=a.t, IF(a.a='<', @ll:=null, null)) `_`,
  a.*
  FROM
  (SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY u, t) a)t1 WHERE t1.a='<'
```

In the test dataset:
`>` means login
`<` means logout

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f81d/48)

**PS:** *Only `"but as of the moment i am constraint to do it in mysql"` is reason for writing it)*